# Recoverable fatal error on nodes after leaving Maintenance mode

Tags: 7, database

Our site was in maintenance mode for several days, and when we came out of maintenance mode a bunch (we don't know how many) of our nodes display this error:

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in DatabaseStatementBase->execute() (line 2136 of includes/database/database.inc).

This error can be found on this page -> http://www.relevantmagazine.com/node/109771
we are able to edit and save the node, but nothing we change fixes the issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably included an object as an argument to one of your query conditions. If you print_r the $args at the line number in the database.inc file, you find out what the placeholders are set to.

Comment: you we're right! we were passing in an array of term objects into on of our queries (instead of an array of tids). thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This error has been discussed [here](http://drupal.org/node/1439236#comment-6048812).

> Update: Systematically unchecked all modules, then went and rechecked sections at a time.

Comment: we're not using Pay Per Node, nor have I ever even heard of it.